# Set variable using CASE expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which looks like this:

```
SELECT  LossCost, CoverageID                
FROM BGILossCost] 
WHERE CoverageID IN (1, 2) AND
      StateID = @StateID AND
      ConstructionID = @ConstructionID AND
      PropertyClassCodeID = @PropertyClassCodeID AND
      (BGIDistrictID = @BGIDistrictID OR BGIDistrictID IS NULL)
```

And returns the following data, which is correct:

```
LossCost                                CoverageID
--------------------------------------- -----------
0.012                                   1
0.034                                   2
```

But what I want to do is set two variables depending in the value of CoverageID

Here is the pseudeo code:

```
SELECT  @Var1 = CASE CoverageID = 1 THEN LossCost END,
  @Var2 = CASE CoverageID = 2 THEN LossCost END             
FROM BGILossCost] 
WHERE CoverageID IN (1, 2) AND
      StateID = @StateID AND
      ConstructionID = @ConstructionID AND
      PropertyClassCodeID = @PropertyClassCodeID AND
      (BGIDistrictID = @BGIDistrictID OR BGIDistrictID IS NULL)
```

I could always do the below but I was hoping I wouldn’t have to join to the same table twice for performance reasons

```
SELECT  @Var1 = LossCost                    
FROM BGILossCost] 
WHERE CoverageID = 1 AND
      StateID = @StateID AND
      ConstructionID = @ConstructionID AND
      PropertyClassCodeID = @PropertyClassCodeID AND
      (BGIDistrictID = @BGIDistrictID OR BGIDistrictID IS NULL) 

SELECT  @Var2 = LossCost                    
FROM BGILossCost] 
WHERE CoverageID = 2 AND
      StateID = @StateID AND
      ConstructionID = @ConstructionID AND
      PropertyClassCodeID = @PropertyClassCodeID AND
      (BGIDistrictID = @BGIDistrictID OR BGIDistrictID IS NULL)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close, doesn't this work:

```
SELECT
  @Var1 = MAX(CASE WHEN CoverageID = 1 THEN LossCost END),
  @Var2 = MAX(CASE WHEN CoverageID = 2 THEN LossCost END)  
FROM BGILossCost
WHERE CoverageID IN (1, 2) AND
      StateID = @StateID AND
      ConstructionID = @ConstructionID AND
      PropertyClassCodeID = @PropertyClassCodeID AND
      (BGIDistrictID = @BGIDistrictID OR BGIDistrictID IS NULL);
```

Comment: I tried this, it looks like it works. But I don't understand why. Need to look at it first thing this am when my head is a little clearer.  Thanks for your help

Comment: If you don't use an aggregate, SQL Server will assign all values from a single, arbitrary row (I hesitate to say the "last" row to avoid any misleading connotations). Since any arbitrary row can't have both CoverageID = 1 *and* CoverageID = 2, letting that one row dictate the assignment will always lead to one of the variables staying NULL.

Comment: OK, now that I had a chance to review it I understand what is going on.  Cool trick.  Thanks for your help.  Much appreciated.